# SignalR no access to Context inside of the HUB

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, websocket, jwt, signalr

I'm bulding notification system, and i have a problem, that caused me to lost a few hours already. my jwt auth works perfectly with the frontend, but when sending (exactly same) jwt token to backend, i've never been able to get access to the Context / Context.User etc.  I Mean, i get the access but User  and basically Everything is null or empty.

I tried every combination of [AllowAnonymous] [Authorize], authorize with schemes, without, authorize on whole hub, only on OnConnectedAsync etc.

If i parse token manually, inside of ConnectedAsync like this, everything works:

```cs
var token = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Query["access_token"];
var userIdString = GetUserIdFromToken(token);
```

```cs
public class TicketHub : Hub
{
    private readonly ITicketsRepository _ticketRepository;
    public TicketHub(ITicketsRepository ticketRepository)
    {
        _ticketRepository = ticketRepository;
    }

    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Policy = "IsAuthenticated")]
    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
      var test = Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
      var test2 = Context; // ->>>> NO CONTEXT HERE
```

my program.cs:  (mostly skipped, only included order of middlewares and auth schema)

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(jwt =>
{
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtConfig:Secret"]);
    jwt.SaveToken = true;
    jwt.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParams;
    jwt.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

            var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                path.StartsWithSegments("/TicketSocket"))
            {
                context.Token = accessToken; 
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
}
);

builder.Services.AddSignalR();
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseWebSockets();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapHub<TicketHub>("/TicketSocket");
}
```

My frontend:

```js
this.connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(`api/TicketSocket`, {
          accessTokenFactory: () => this.$auth.strategy.token.get(),
        })
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .build()
```

Comment: Why you are using `.withUrl(`api/TicketSocket``, instead of `.withUrl(`/TicketSocket`` when you are connecting the hub in frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the `Authorize` attribute on `OnConnectedAsync` is ineffective. You need to put it on TicketHub.

Comment: As i said, i tried many combinations of this attribute. Here i've just pasted the last-tried one.  
`[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] `  above the TicketHub,  causes the 401 Unauthorized on version negotiation.
http://localhost:4029/api/TicketSocket/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1